# Edit text values getting cleared when list view is scrolled

Tags: android

I had an layout which contains list view in which there will be edit texts.
After entering the data in edit texts and the after scrolling the text screen the edit text value are getting cleared.

The problem i am facing is that not able to save the edit text values after screen scrolling.

```
package com.nafaes.nafaesgate.Adaptors;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nafaes.nafaesgate.R;
import com.nafaes.nafaesgate.activities.BullionWithdrawActivity;
import com.nafaes.nafaesgate.activities.OrdersHistoryActivity;
import com.nafaes.nafaesgate.activities.ReserveActivity;


import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Mounika on 5/15/2017.
 */

public class BullionWithdraw_list extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> barname_array=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> quantity_array=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> bullion_array=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> bullionId_array=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> detailsid=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> userOty_array=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Double> bullionweight_array = new ArrayList<Double>();
    Double serCharges;
    Double barsTotal;
    Double finalCharges;
    String bullionvalue;
    Double quantityValue = 0.0;
    ArrayList<Integer> quantityValue_array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String bullionWithdrawvalue;
    String bullionSrveQuanEmp = "";
    Double bullionQuanFloat;
    String quanLimit;
    Double limitDouble;
    String limitQuantity = "";
    Double totalQuanVal;
    Double quanValue = 0.0;
    Double serviceChargeVal = 0.0;
    Double serviceChargeDouble;
    String emptyStrng = "";
    String serviceChargeEdit;
    Integer data = 0;
    String servicetext;
    String deliveryText;
    Double totalvalue = 0.0;
    Double serValue = 0.0;
    Integer  finaldelCharges;





    Context context;


    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public BullionWithdraw_list(BullionWithdrawActivity WithdrawActivity, ArrayList<String> barname_array,
                                ArrayList<String> quantity_array,
                                ArrayList<String> bullion_array,
                                ArrayList<Integer>bullionId_array,
                                ArrayList<String> userOty_array,
                                ArrayList<Integer> detailsid,
                                Double serCharges,
                                ArrayList<Double> bullionweight_array,Double serviceChargeDouble,ArrayList<Integer> quantityValue_array,String serviceChargeEdit
                                 )
    {

        this.barname_array=barname_array;
        this.quantity_array=quantity_array;
        this.bullion_array=bullion_array;
        this.bullionId_array=bullionId_array;
        this.detailsid=detailsid;
        this.userOty_array = userOty_array;
        this.serCharges = serCharges;
        this.bullionweight_array = bullionweight_array;
        this.serviceChargeDouble = serviceChargeDouble;
        this.quantityValue_array = quantityValue_array;
        this.serviceChargeEdit = serviceChargeEdit;



        context=WithdrawActivity;



        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        Log.e("Service","63 "+serCharges);
        Log.e("De","63 "+detailsid);


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bullionId_array.size();
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv1,tv2;
        EditText et1;
        int pos;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final BullionWithdraw_list.Holder holder=new BullionWithdraw_list.Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bullion_withdraw_list, null);
        holder.tv1=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.barname);
        holder.tv2=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        holder.et1=(EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.withdraw);
        rowView.setTag(holder);

        Log.e("QuanArray","143 "+quantityValue_array);
        Log.e("Weight Array","148 "+bullionweight_array);

        quanValue = 0.0;
        serviceChargeVal = 0.0;


        holder.tv1.setText(barname_array.get(position));
        holder.tv2.setText(quantity_array.get(position));




        //quantityValue_array.clear();
        holder.et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }


            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                //if (quantityValue_array.g)

                SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("finalcharges",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                finaldelCharges = preferences.getInt("finalcharges",0);
                Log.e("Prefs","179 "+finaldelCharges);

                serviceChargeEdit = "0.0";
                serviceChargeVal = 0.0;
                quanValue = 0.0;

                holder.et1.setTag(position);

                if (!holder.et1.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    //quantityValue_array.add(holder.et1.getText().toString());
                    quantityValue_array.set(position, Integer.valueOf(holder.et1.getText().toString()));
                    Log.e("List", "172 " + quantityValue_array);

                } else {
                    quantityValue_array.set(position, 0);
                }
                Log.e("ListEditText", "172 " + quantityValue_array);
                Log.e("Weight", "187 " + bullionweight_array);
                    serValue = 0.0;
                for (int j = 0;j<quantityValue_array.size();j++){
                    serValue =  serValue + quantityValue_array.get(j) * bullionweight_array.get(j) * serCharges;
                    Log.e("Charges at row number","196 "+ j +"  is " + serValue);


                }
                totalvalue = serValue+finaldelCharges;

                String finalserCharges = String.valueOf(serValue);
                Log.e("Text","208 "+totalvalue);
                ((BullionWithdrawActivity) context).callMethod(finalserCharges,detailsid);


            }



            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });


        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddCart.class);
//                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try--> under getView

```
if (convertView == null) {

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)    
    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.bullion_withdraw_list, null);

    holder.et1= (EditText) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.elementUpdateScore);


    convertView.setTag(holder);

} else {

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

}
    //binding data from array list
    holder.et1.setText(et1[position]);
    holder.et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int before, int count) {
            //setting data to array, when changed
            et1[position] = s.toString();
      //rest your code
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

return convertView;
```

}